# How can we transform pairwise mapped strings to multiple groups of strings based on a score?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

If pairwise mapping of words has score more than 0.5, then group them together.If any other keyword having score more than 0.5 with a group, add the keyword to the group.

Example:

Input:

```
word1              word2       score
hello           hello world    0.75
hello world     hi world       0.555
hello           hi world       0
good morning    hello          0
good morning    morning        0.75
morning         hello          0
morning         hello world    0
morning         hi world       0
good morning    hello world    0
good morning    hi world       0
```

Output:

```
word                 group
hello                 1
hello world           1
hi world              1
good morning          2
morning               2
```

Comment: Can you explain why `morning` is `2` ?

Comment: morning and good morning have score 0 with all the words in group1

Comment: Super, answer was edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First filter rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html):

```
df1 = df[df['score'].gt(0.5)]
print (df1)
          word1        word2  score
0         hello  hello world  0.750
1   hello world     hi world  0.555
4  good morning      morning  0.750
```

Use `networkx` with [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html) for dictionary:

```
import networkx as nx

# Create the graph from the dataframe
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from(df1[['word1','word2']].itertuples(index=False))

connected_components = nx.connected_components(g)

# Find the component id of the nodes
node2id = {}
for cid, component in enumerate(connected_components):
    for node in component:
        node2id[node] = cid + 1
```

Last reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), remove duplicates by [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and last use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column:

```
df2 = df1[['word1','word2']].stack().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('word')
df2['group'] = df2['word'].map(node2id)
print (df2)
           word  group
0         hello      1
1   hello world      1
2      hi world      1
3  good morning      2
4       morning      2
```

Answer (score 0):

[@jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60275137/5156887) is good, but I wanted to add a warning about this algorithm.

This method of grouping by using pairwise scores doesn't always give the best results, since ***the similarity score isn't transitive***. For example consider "ABC", "BCD", "CDE" .... "WXY", "XYZ".  Each adjacent pair has a good score, but grouping "ABC" and "XYZ" together probably is a mistake.

If this is a problem for your use case, consider other algorithms. One possibility is "Hierarchical Clustering with Centroid Linkage". This algorithm treats all points within some distance of a centroid as part of the same group. In this example "BCD" might be one centroid and "ABC" and "CDE" get grouped with it.

For a nice intro into this general topic of "record linkage", see https://dedupe.io/documentation/how-it-works.html.